# ListView not updating when dragging its scrollbar thumb?

Tags: windows, listview, delphi, tlistview

Even though the timer is constantly adding new items, this is NOT shown while dragging the listview's scrollbar thumb.

(Does update as expected when a custom style has been set for the listview)

How to force the listview to update properly?

Reproduction:

```
var
  I: Integer;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  I := I + 1;
  ListView1.Items.Add.caption := IntToStr(I);
end;
```

Comment: Actually, the items are updated / added to the `Listview`, but the scrollbar range is not updated while the mouse holds the scrollbar thumb grip active.  If you can explain in details why this is a problem, maybe there is a solution. Otherwise use the scroll buttons instead of the thumb grip, as they don't prevent scroll range updates.

Comment: Tom Brunberg:
as i have said: items ARE added but, while using the thumb, neither the listview nor its scrollbar update (UNLESS IsCustomStyleActive). this is a problem because the listview is updated from a thread, and the idea is to scroll it to the end after a new item has been added IF previously at bottom -- this however gets broken since `TScrollInfo.nTrackPos` is "frozen", while `nMax` does increase

Comment: There are other ways to automatically scroll to the last item. You can also click **on** the scrollbar without hitting both buttons and the thumb. Holding down the Shift key and clicking at any position will even skip the page wise scroll.

Comment: AmigoJack: irrelevant. to begin with, you are describing scrolling manually and not automatically (i.e. by code); regardless, since the thumb is not involved, `nPos`/`nTrackPos` are not "frozen", and so determining whether the scrollbar is at the bottom can be computed as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the text of your question, you also say in a comment that "... the idea is to scroll it (the `TListView`) to the end after a new item has been added IF previously at bottom".

The following does that:

```
var
  I: integer;

procedure TForm7.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  KeepLastItemVisible: boolean;
begin
  // Check if scrolled to the end of list before adding a new item
  KeepLastItemVisible := false;
  with ListView1 do
    with Items do
      if Count > 1 then
        if Item[Count-1].index = TopItem.Index - 1 + VisibleRowCount then
          KeepLastItemVisible := true;

  // Add new item
  I := I + 1;
  ListView1.Items.Add.caption := IntToStr(I);

  // Conditionally force scrolling last row into view
  if KeepLastItemVisible then
    with ListView1.Items do
      Item[Count-1].MakeVisible(False);
end;
```

Comment: you forgot to check if `TopItem <> nil`, else error; does not work for e.g. ViewStyle of vsIcon. better solution is to get nMax on SB_THUMBTRACK and use that instead of real value until SB_THUMBPOSITION. regardless, these are all workarounds: when custom style is set the listview does update as expected so this is definitely possible